# Where is the elementaryOS Photos Application library stored?

Tags: photos

I want to use the elementaryOS Photos app for my photos but I have multiple Systems and want them to share the same photo organizational structure and ofc all edits.

With digiKam I have a mysql database that i can sync, so that I have the same structure on both system.
Does elementaryOS Photos have something like that? Or how can I achieve similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look in `~/.local/share/io.elementary.photos/data/` to see if it contains what you need.